# Prolog: how to extract lists from complex term

Tags: list, prolog

I am tasked with extending some existing Prolog code and I have run into an issue with the structure of a complex term. 
This complex term is passed as a parameter to a Prolog predicate that I am writing. Problem is that I need to extract two lists from this complex term and the structure of the term is not known in advanced or fixed.

Specifically, let's say I have a term "Param" like this:

```
lam(_G23075,
   drs([_G23084], [eq(_G23084, person), ant(_G23084, mask, sg)])+_G23075*_G23084)
```

The drs term above has the two lists that I would like to extract.

If Param had the drs term only, I could do this:

```
drs(L1, L2) = Param.
```

And then L1 and L2 would contain the lists. 
How could this work with the complex term structure given above?

Cheers,

Martin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can deconstruct the term e.g. with `=..`:

The following predicate `extract_drs(+Term,-L1,-L2)` returns the two occurring lists. It may have multiple solutions if there are multiple occurrences of matching terms.

```
extract_drs(drs(L1,L2),R1,R2) :- !,R1=L1,R2=L2. % the cut avoids that L1 or L2 are inspected
extract_drs(Term,L1,L2) :-
  compound(Term),           % check if it is a compound term and not a number, variable, etc.
  Term =.. [_Functor|Args], % get the arguments of Term
  member(Arg,Args),         % choose one argument
  extract_drs(Arg,L1,L2).   % and try to extract there the drs term
```

Comment: Just to confirm: This solution works fine. Tks, Daniel!

Answer (score 1):

I would write

```
extract_drs(Term,L1,L2) :-
  compound(Term), (Term = drs(L1,L2) ; arg(_,Term,Arg), extract_drs(Arg,L1,L2)).
```

*edit* as noted by danielp, it's a SWI_prolog extension that allows to use arg/3 with first argument unbound. Then should be replaced by

```
extract_drs(Term,L1,L2) :-
  compound(Term), (Term = drs(L1,L2) ; Term =.. [_|Args], member(Arg,Args), extract_drs(Arg,L1,L2)).
```

Comment: If I let the first argument of arg/3 unspecified, I get an `Instantiation error in argument 1 of arg/3` with SICStus Prolog.

Comment: [Docs](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=arg/3) states that possibly genarg/3 supports `(?Arg, +Term, ?Value)`

Comment: [ISO](http://www.deransart.fr/prolog/bips.html#arg) states that the template is `arg(+integer,+compound_term,?term)` but I'm not used to read the ISO spec. Anyway, if SWI is used, using `arg` to iterate over the arguments is nicer than `=..` and `member/2`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the hints. I will try them out soonest (can't do it right now, due to reasons beyond my control).